# Can't start Django project: No Module Named django.core

Tags: django, linux, django-admin

I recently installed Python 2.7 and django 1.4.1 on a Linux machine. I thought the install went successfully, however, when I try and run the command: `django-admin.py startproject newproject`, I get the following message:

```
andrew@server [~/django]# django-admin.py startproject newproject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 2, in ?
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

I have found a few similar questions, but none seemed to fix the issue. When I open python through the shell and `import django`, it works, so I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Check which `django-admin.py` you are executing.

Comment: Once you find it, also check whether the `#!` line of it lists the same python executable you're running in your shell.

Comment: try this: 1)import django  2)dajngo.__file__. After this check core exist there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend issuing the following from a Python prompt:

```
import site
print site.getsitepackages()[1]
```

This will provide you with the path where your site-packages live.  This directory would be the first place I would assume your django installation to have been placed. Or you can issue the following at a command prompt:

```
ls `python -c "import site; print site.getsitepackages()[1]"`
```

If you do not find your django installation in the above directory you can:

1. Reinstall django and ensure it ends up where you expect
2. Continue searching the paths used by Python

If you decide to continue searching for your installation you can inspect `sys.paths` and look through the list of paths to determine if django was installed in one of these paths.

Lastly, you could have potentially installed django in your "user" site-packages.  This would be done by including `--user` when you ran setup.py.  If you did this you can find your user site-packages issuing the following from a Python prompt:

```
import site
print site.getusersitepackages()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue ..

The first change I made was to set an alias so that python 2.5 is used. The second was to move /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages to the beginning of PYTHONPATH. I made these changes by adding two lines to my .profile:

export PYTHONPATH="/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
alias python=python2.5

Comment: OP is using Linux instead of OSX, he might not be able to find such paths.